# JQuery : TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function import_data_to_sheet(json)
{   
$.each( json , function(row, element) {
    row = parseInt(row);    
    $.each(element, function(col, val) {            
            col = parseInt(col);
            //sheet.getCell(row, col).value( val.v );
                           console.log(row + col + val.v );
    });     
});
}
```

Someone please tell me why the above function wont work for var data1 below but works fine with data2 yet they are of the same type and format (I think ;-) ). I need to iterate through data1 using the function above but I'm getting the error message: 'TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a'

```
var data1 = [[{"v":"Lake Lanotoo"},{"v":4.7}],[{"v":"Mt Vaea Botanical Reserve"},{"v":2}],[{"v":"Apai Manono-tai"},{"v":0.96}],[{"v":"Apolima-uta (e)"},{"v":0.18}],[{"v":"Asaga'"},{"v":0.2}],[{"v":"Asau"},{"v":2.37}],[{"v":"Aua'la"},{"v":0.79}],[{"v":"Aufaga Lepa(e)"},{"v":0.04}],[{"v":"Eva Anoamaa"},{"v":0.2}],[{"v":"Faala Palauli"},{"v":1.33}],[{"v":"Fagaee" },{"v":0.27}],[{"v":"Fagalii Vaimauga"},{"v":0.04}],[{"v":"Fagamalo"},{"v":0.5600000000000001}],[{"v" :"Fagasa"},{"v":0.17}],[{"v":"Falealupo"},{"v":1.96}],[{"v":"Faleu Manono-uta"},{"v":0.24}],[{"v":"Faleula" },{"v":5.53}],[{"v":"Fasitoo-tai"},{"v":1.67}],[{"v":"Fatuvalu"},{"v":0.03}],[{"v":"Foailalo"},{"v":0.59}],[{"v":"Fogatuli"},{"v":0.49}],[{"v":"Fuailoloo Mulifanua (e)"},{"v":0.05}],[{"v":"Gagaifo Lefaga" },{"v":0.62}],[{"v":"Lalovi Mulifanua (e)"},{"v":0.89}],[{"v":"Lelepa"},{"v":0.16}],[{"v":"Lepa (e)" },{"v":0.2}],[{"v":"Lepuiai Manono-tai"},{"v":1.81}],[{"v":"Leusoalii Anoamaa"},{"v":0.11}],[{"v":"LuuaFaga"},{"v":0.23}],[{"v":"Manase"},{"v":0.48}],[{"v":"Matatufu (e)"},{"v":0.01}],[{"v":"Matautu Falelatai" },{"v":0.2}],[{"v":"Neiafu (e)"},{"v":1.01}],[{"v":"Nofoalii Aana"},{"v":2.93}],[{"v":"Papa Palauli" },{"v":0.3}],[{"v":"Poutasi Falealili"},{"v":2.25}],[{"v":"Puapua"},{"v":1.23}],[{"v":"Saleapaga Lepa(e)"},{"v":0.05}],[{"v":"Saletagaloa & Foua (Salelologa)"},{"v":0.24}],[{"v":"Salimu Faga (e)"},{"v" :0.51}],[{"v":"Salua Manono-tai (e)"},{"v":1.67}],[{"v":"Samatau Falelatai (e)"},{"v":1.09}],[{"v":"SaoluafataAnoamaa"},{"v":1.04}],[{"v":"Sapapalii"},{"v":1.77}],[{"v":"Sapini Faga (e)"},{"v":0.36}],[{"v":"Satalafai& Sapulu (Salelologa)"},{"v":0.12}],[{"v":"Satapuala Aana"},{"v":2.46}],[{"v":"Sataua (e)"},{"v":0.54}],[{"v":"Satoalepai"},{"v":0.31}],[{"v":"Savaia Lefaga (e)"},{"v":0.05}],[{"v":"Siufaga Faga"},{"v" :0.26}],[{"v":"Siufaga Falelatai (e)"},{"v":0.08}],[{"v":"Solosolo Anoamaa"},{"v":0.57}],[{"v":"TafagamanuLefaga (e)"},{"v":0.05}],[{"v":"Tafatafa Falealili (e)"},{"v":0.12}],[{"v":"Vailuutai Aana"},{"v":0.93}],[{"v":"Vaisala"},{"v":0.37}],[{"v":"Vaitoomuli"},{"v":0.34}],[{"v":"Vaiusu Faleata"},{"v":0.53}],[{"v":"Vaovai Falealili (e)"},{"v":0.92}],[{"v":"Vavau Lepa (e)"},{"v":0.03}],[{"v":"Uafato"},{"v" :14}],[{"v":"Afaga Tele"},{"v":1.43}],[{"v":"Ava o sina"},{"v":0.07000000000000001}],[{"v":"Faaofi laulu" },{"v":0.34}],[{"v":"Fausaga"},{"v":0.73}],[{"v":"punaoa"},{"v":0.3}],[{"v":"Vaiee"},{"v":10.26}],[{"v" :"Palolo Deep"},{"v":0.22}],[{"v":"Lake Lanotoo"},{"v":26}],[{"v":"O Le Pupu Pue"},{"v":28.57}],[{"v" :"Mt Vaea Botanical Reserve"},{"v":0.52}],[{"v":"Tusitala Historic"},{"v":1.5}],[{"v":"Fusi-TafitaolaReef"},{"v":null}],[{"v":"Matautu Lowland Swamp Forest"},{"v":0.16}],[{"v":"Mount Silisili"},{"v":89}],[{"v":"Saanapu-Sataoa"},{"v":0.75}],[{"v":"Sasina"},{"v":5}],[{"v":"Tafua Rainforest Reserve"},{"v" :60}],[{"v":"Aleipata Marine Protected Area"},{"v":50}],[{"v":"Safata Marine Protected Area"},{"v":40}],[{"v":"Falealupo Forest Preserve"},{"v":12.15}],[{"v":"Togitogiga"},{"v":0.03}]];

var data2 = [[{"v":1991},{"v":58}],[{"v":1992},{"v":63}],[{"v" :1993},{"v":74}],[{"v":1994},{"v":29}],[{"v":1995},{"v":33}],[{"v":1996},{"v":19}],[{"v":1997},{"v":37 }],[{"v":1998},{"v":88}],[{"v":1999},{"v":33}],[{"v":2000},{"v":46}],[{"v":2001}]]
```

Comment: The error is not in the code shown. Where is the error coming from, really? What is `sheet`? What does `sheet.getCell()` does ? What does it return? What does `getCellResult.value()` do?

Comment: sheet is an instance of a web spreadsheet that I'm trying to populate with data1. I've commented it out and replaced with console.log

Comment: Can you please create a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: @ObirieniSimeo Well, precisely, with console.log, I don't see any error: http://jsfiddle.net/e8u12jqb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks guys, I found out where the error was when I tried to create a jsfiddle.
I was trying to store this data in a html element in the following not so smart manner:
`var html ='<div id="foo" data-rows="' + data1 + '">;'` and because of un-escaped special characters (I think), it would lead to invalid HTML markup hence break my JavaScript code.

I'm now using jQuery.data which works fine i.e. 
     `$('#foo').data('rows', data1);`

Thanks @laruiss and @Luc

Comment: I would strongly recommend building your dom elements with this approach:
var html = $("<div>").attr("id","foo").data("rows",data1);

Then appending it to whatever you want.